# How to change the default gray color of the QgsComposition background?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm building a map, with elements like QgsComposerMap of course, but also QgsComposerLabel, QgsComposerLegend ,etc...
Each of these elements has a boolean "setBackgroundEnabled" property, to make them white backgrounded or not.
But when aggregating these white backgrounded elements in the QgsComposition, we can see gray bands between them, caused by the deepest gray background. And it's printed when saved as image !

As for canvas, ( i mean canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)), is there a way to set the color of the overall QgsComposition background (the deepest one) ?

Is there something like :

```
comp = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
comp.setCompositionColor(Qt.white)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By resizing the paper, one can get the white background.

```
mapRenderer = QgsMapRenderer()
comp = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
comp.setPaperSize(w,h) #210 and 297 millimeters by default
```

If `w` and `h` are too small (and so the paper) compared to image dimensions, you'll get gray bands as described in my question.